# How to use Get-PnPFolder to show SharePoint folder perm

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using PowerShell PNP to try and read the permissions of a folder but the command Get-PnPFolder does not appear to include the permissions.

I tried the code listed here but the permissions collection are empty. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221118/retrieve-permissions-at-folder-and-file-level-in-powershell/221513 . This small sample below is what I used for testing.

```
$spserver = 'https://myportal.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/'
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $spserver –UseWebLogin
$foldername = 'myFormLibraryName'
$folderObj = Get-PnPFolder -Url $foldername -Includes ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments, ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments 
$folderObj.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
$folderObj.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments
```

The results of the code will return "`collection has not been initialized`". How do I get a list of the permissions for a SharePoint folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to get the code to work with Get-PnPFolder and used the code below as an alternative.

```
$spserver = 'https://myportal.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/'
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $spserver –UseWebLogin
$ctx=Get-PnPContext
$foldername = 'Documents'
$web = $ctx.Web
$list = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle($foldername)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host 'count is ' $list.ItemCount
$roleass = $list.RoleAssignments
$ctx.Load($roleass)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host 'loaded'
foreach($rol in $roleass) {
    $ctx.Load($rol.Member)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host $rol.Member.Title
}
```